# Is there a faster way to update a deployment in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, terminal

To deploy a meteor app, you enter `meteor deploy my_first_meteor_app.meteor.com`

To update the deployment, is there a faster way than typing the above command again? It's quite tedious if you have a long domain name like the one in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can user aliases (nothing to do with Meteor). This is how you do it on a Mac:

```
alias new_name='command to be performed'
```

After which you must store the changes permanently in the file:

```
~/.bash_profile
```

See a full explanation here: http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_creating_aliases_commands

Also, you can try running `meteor deploy` without the site name. I don't remember if that works or not though. meteor deploy does remember old settings files that were used, but I'm not sure if it remembers the site name you used too.